# R Model control for normal distribution with qqnorm on data with missing values ERROR

Tags: r, distribution

### ***Problem***

I have a some data from a repeated measures study, where some subjects dropped out or have random missing observations between observations (non-dropout missing values). I want to test if the data is following a normal distribution with a QQ plot.

### ***Attempt***

I have shared a sample dataset with one outcome (wght) [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18g_sUToTP1X6f5S2ODMGV2qEcFC86I0_/view?usp=sharing).

I load my data:

```
df <- tbl_df(read.csv(
  file="normality.csv", 
  header=TRUE, sep=","))
```

Then I try to make a QQ plot of the wght outcome using the qqnorm function:

```
qqnorm(normality$wght)
```

But I get an error, which i assume is because some subjects have missing values in the outcome:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'ylim' value
```

What can be done to fix this error, or is there a more appropriate way to test if my data is following a normal distribution?

Comment: I don't think it's the `NA` values. Check this `x = rexp(20, 1);
x[2:10] = NA;
qqnorm(x)` Make sure your variable is `numeric` and not `character`. Maybe try `qqnorm(as.numeric(normality$wght))`

Comment: Additionally, check `shapiro.test` to perform a statistical test to assess normality of your data. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test and here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/shapiro.test.html

Comment: You're right! Silly me.. Thanks for the additional infor re. the shapiro test!

Comment: @AntoniosK I tried doing the `shapiro.test`, but i have a "sample size" of more than 5000. The real sample size is around 2300, but with the repeated measures there are 15,000 measurements. Do you know of another test that could handle more than 5,000 observations?

Comment: Maybe you can try the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test then.